# How to create dates using datetime based on day of the week?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I want to write a block of code using `datetime` so that if `datetime.now()` is saturday or friday after 4pm, create a datetime object for 4pm on the friday which passed.

I have the following completed:

```
from datetime import datetime

datenow = datetime.now()
if datenow.isoweekday() == 6 or (datenow.isoweekday() in [5] and datenow.hour >=16): 
           ## change datenow to the passing friday at 4pm.
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full solution:

```
def set_prev_iso_week_day(val, iso_week_day):
    """
    Set ISO week day.
    New date will be less or equal than input date.
    :param val: datetime or date
    :type val: datetime.datetime | datetime.date
    :param iso_week_day: ISO week day to set
    :type iso_week_day: int
    :return: datetime.datetime | datetime.date
    """
    if val.isoweekday() == iso_week_day:
        return val
    diff = iso_week_day - val.isoweekday()
    diff = -diff if diff < 0 else 7 - diff
    val -= timedelta(days=diff)
    return val

datenow = set_prev_iso_week_day(datenow, 5).replace(hour=16,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0)
```

or use my lib [t77_date](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/t77-date) and use:

```
from t77_date.constants import ISO_FRIDAY
from t77_date.datetime import set_prev_iso_week_day


datenow = set_prev_iso_week_day(datenow, ISO_FRIDAY).replace(hour=16,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from datetime import timedelta

def mod_time(datenow):
  if datenow.isoweekday() in [6,7]:#for Saturday or Sunday
    print datenow
    datenow -= timedelta(days=datenow.isoweekday()-5) #Going back to Friday
    print datenow
    datenow = datenow.replace(hour=16,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0) #Making 4pm
    print datenow

  return datenow
```

```